# Redirect for pages has not yet translated

Tags: c#, redirect, kentico, culture

When users visit to our page (ex: en-us/something), they want to change language (ex: vi-vn/something).
But the page doesn't exist. So I want to redirect to home page or to the current page (ex: en-us/something).

I'm using k12, is this config available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, so you'd need to test it yourself.
In the **Settings** application under **Content** you'll find the **Multilingual** category. Here you have a checkbox **Combine with default culture**.
According to the tooltip: Indicates if default culture version of the page should be used when the page is not translated.

Comment: It doesn't correct what I want. when I uncheck "Combine with default culture.", every pages has not yet translated will be not found. when it checked, the pages will show content from default language

Comment: In that case I think I misunderstood the question. I thought one of the options your were considering was, showing the untranslated page in the default language.